# Can I specify a group of approvers and reviewers for individual folders in a SharePoint document Library?

Tags: sharepoint-2013, sharepoint-workflow

We are using a SharePoint document library for holding project documents. These projects are separated into folders within the library and each project folder then contains multiple sub folders.

I'm looking to set up a few approval workflows for different formats of word document. My assumption is that if I create the workflows in the base folder of the document library then they should be visible to the sub folders.

I'd then like to have a different set of reviewers and approvers based on the Project folder. Is this possible and can you point me it the right direction?

Many Thanks.